# Dynamically Remove Node from ChildFactory.Detachable

Tags: netbeans-platform, outline-view

I am currently working on Outline View, where I creating children by using `ChildFactory.Detachable`, which is working properly.

I implemented the `PropertyChangeListener` on this `ChildFactory` where I dynamically adding and removing the nodes given below

```
public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {     
    if ("ADD".equals(evt.getPropertyName())) {
        this.refresh(false);
    } else if ("REMOVE".equals(evt.getPropertyName())) {
        this.refresh(false);
    } 
}
```

Here the structure is `RootNode` and its child nodes and child node also can contain its own child nodes. 
The problem is, whenever I try to remove the node from any root node the expansion sign(+) is not removed.

I gone through the ["No Expansion Icon When No Children (Part 1) - Blog | /Oracle"](https://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/entry/no_expansion_key_when_no) from Geertjan's Blog but its for adding new node and not removing.

If anybody has any idea about it please let me know.

Thanks is advance.